# Convert Data Frame column into String

Tags: python, string

I have an embedded SQL query which returns the expected values into a Python data frame.

I am looking to either:

a) convert a column of values from my data frame, into a string (where each value is separated by a comma), or
b) directly create a string of values from my query without having to create a data frame in the first place

expected result is the same, a string of values (where each value is separated by a comma)

Hope someone can advise...

Comment: Can you provide an example of current input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

A column of numerical values in a DF can be combined into one string as in the simple example below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 4.0] })

s = ','.join(df['col'].astype(str).values)

print(s)
```

giving the string:

```
1.2,2.3,3.1,4.0
```